# Passar parâmetro para uma função de callback

Tags: javascript, parâmetros

Preciso passar um parâmetro para uma função de callback.

Na verdade a ideia é a seguinte:

Pesquiso no banco membros de uma equipe, no caso a tabela é `PESSOA_EQUIPE` e neste banco existe os dados do código dela e o identificador, se ela é uma pessoa normal, se é um líder, um auxiliar. Com estás informações vou na tabela de pessoa e pesquisa quais são as pessoas, para pegar o nome e alguns outros dados.

O código é o seguinte:

```
var transaction = db.transaction(["tbl_PESSOAS"]);
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("tbl_PESSOAS");
for(var i = 0; i < arrayCursor.length; i++){
    var auxObj = new Object();
    auxObj = arrayCursor[i].FLG_IDENT_PESSO; //PRECISO QUE ESTE OBJETO SEJA VISUALIZADO DENTRO DO PONTO 01

    var request = objectStore.get(arrayCursor[i].COD_IDENT_PESSO);
    request.onsuccess = function (event) { //MINHA FUNÇÃO DE CALLBACK
        var arrayVelhoAux = new Object();
        pessoa = event.target.result;

        arrayVelhoAux.FLG_IDENT_PESSO = auxObj; //PONTO 01, É AQUI QUE PRECISA SER VISTO
        arrayVelhoAux.COD_IDENT_PESSO = pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO;
        arrayVelhoAux.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO = pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO;
        arrayVelhoAux.FLG_STATU_PESSO = pessoa.FLG_STATU_PESSO;

        arrayVelho.push(arrayVelhoAux);

        console.log(arrayVelho);
    }
}
transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {}
```

Comment: antes da fazer push para arrayVelho, o dado do auxObj aparece dentro do `console.log(arrayVelhoAux);` ?

Comment: Sim. ele aparece

Comment: Então, neste sentido, o parâmetro já foi passado para sua função callback, onde está o problema então?

Comment: Experimente iniciar o objeto:  `var arrayVelho = {};` O push só funciona para array.